# WordPress - Show custom taxonomy parent category on child category slug

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using [GeoCraft Theme](http://www.98london.com/) by InkThemes as a Business Directory for a new website. As other themes like this, it was made to use listings only for one city, but I want to expand it to show listings for different cities.

To do that, I'll use on the Theme's custom taxonomy for cateogires (listcat), Parent Categories for the cities, and Child Categories for the business category itself.

So, I need something like this:

- New York (Parent) - URL: mywebsite.com/listcat/new-york/
- New York >> Restaurants - URL: mywebsite.com/listcat/new-york/restaurants/
- Los Angeles >> Restaurants - URL: mywebsite.com/listcat/los-angeles/restaurants/
- Los Angeles >> Bars - URL: mywebsite.com/listcat/los-angeles/bars/
- Chicago >> Restaurants - URL: mywebsite.com/listcat/chicago/restaurants/

...and so on.

Instead, the child categories don't show the parent categories (new-york, los-angeles and other cities names).

Does anyone know how I can start achieving this? I searched for same questions but didn't find. I know how to use WordPress and use it for years but can accomplish this task.
Edit:

I found the code used to register the category taxonomy for the directory listings:

```
// Register custom taxonomy for category
register_taxonomy(CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE, array(POST_TYPE), array("hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_LABEL,
    'labels' => array('name' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_TITLE,
        'singular_name' => CUSTOM_MENU_SIGULAR_CAT,
        'search_items' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_SEARCH,
        'popular_items' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_SEARCH,
        'all_items' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_ALL,
        'parent_item' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_PARENT,
        'parent_item_colon' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_PARENT_COL,
        'edit_item' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_EDIT,
        'update_item' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_UPDATE,
        'add_new_item' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_ADDNEW,
        'new_item_name' => CUSTOM_MENU_CAT_NEW_NAME,),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    "rewrite" => true)
);
```

Probably I should change something with rewrite, anyone already did this?

Comment: Hey guys, I did it.

So for guys trying to do the same thing, it's a simple add you should use at the "rewrite" information for your custom taxonomy.

Instead of:

       "rewrite" => true)

I added this:

     "rewrite" => array('hierarchical' => true))

Simples as that.

Comment: You could answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks  that  worked!

Just add  'hierarchical' => true   in the rewrite=>array()  of the taxonomy  as  follows:

`register_taxonomy( 'BLABLABLABIG-TAXONOMY', 'talalalala', array( 'hierarchical' => true,. . . . . . . . . .  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'categories','hierarchical' => true ))`

Then Go  back in the Permalink settings and save them to flush the  rewrite  rules and voila!